# Start new process as pane in iTerm

Tags: iterm2

I work in iTerm a lot, and I am using a script that starts a new process. By default, the process starts in a new tab.

Is there any way to tell iTerm that I want to start new processes in a vertical pane instead? Alternatively, is there an easy way to merge two tabs into a split-pane window without using the mouse?

Comment: A lazy answer from me (hence it's a comment), you may find this reasonably do-able within a screen session. Or maybe tmux would work?

Comment: the process that i am starting is actually a tmux session, it still starts in a new tab.